# Domino traveller resource usage

Tags: ibm-domino

Does anyone know how resource hungry traveller is? I was informed that it's really resource intensive, is that true? Does anyone have any experience running traveller on the same server as xpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2 and 8.5.3 Traveler performance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes852-trav-perf/). It states

> To support more than 2000 (or number reached in our tests) active Lotus Notes Traveler users, customers need to deploy more than one Lotus Notes Traveler 8.5.2 64-bit server. The processor utilization on the Lotus Domino mail server should be monitored to ensure that the mail server can handle the added activity from the Lotus Notes Traveler users at peak load.
>   Note that Lotus Notes Traveler is a memory-intensive application and it is best to deploy Lotus Domino 64-bit servers on Windows 64-bit operating systems to support large numbers of mobile device users.